# Error when unit testing in ReactJS Missing library modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing

I am writing a test website using ReactJs & Node for a class and am having difficulties running tests.
I have tried reinstalling packages via npm install. Upgrading and downgrading to certain versions of "testing-library" but that leads to more failed tests ive tried installing npm i helpers/helper

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "landingpage-react-template",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "database.js": "^0.0.1",
    "detect-file": "^1.0.0",
    "detect-libc": "^2.0.1",
    "emailjs-com": "^2.6.4",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.4.0",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.6",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mv": "^2.1.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.8.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-youtube": "^9.0.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.23.2",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.5.1",
    "smooth-scroll": "^16.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.7",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

And this is the error im getting after running npm test

```
 FAIL  src/pages/components/resetPasswordPage/resetPasswordComponent.test.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@testing-library/dom/dist/helpers.js' from 'node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/utils/misc/getWindow.js'

    Require stack:
      node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/utils/misc/getWindow.js
      node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/utils/dataTransfer/Clipboard.js
      node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/event/behavior/click.js
      node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/event/dispatchEvent.js
      node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/document/prepareDocument.js
      node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/setup/setup.js
      node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/setup/index.js
      node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/index.js
      src/pages/components/resetPasswordPage/resetPasswordComponent.test.jsx

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/utils/misc/getWindow.js:5:18)
```

Answer (score 3):

`@testing-library/dom` is a [peer dependency](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/blob/main/package.json#L60) of `user-event` and needs to be installed separately in your project.